# Flickering on Android 2.3 while navigating from one page to other one: Phone Gap

Tags: cordova

I am developing a phone gap application using cordova 2.2 , its all worked but while navigating from one page to other there is not smooth Transition on android v 2.3 , its work well on v 4.0 and above , i dig around and google but there is no any relevent solution i get, i use a single HTML file for whole the application using Div tag , i tried with

```
.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning .ui-page {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.ui-page
 {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 }
```

but not worked at all.there is white flickering occurs while navigating.

Comment: Even with $.mobile.defaultPageTransition  = 'none'; ?

Comment: no its works fine for transition value set to "none"...:)

Comment: as per my understanding problem is in jquery mobile transition not phoengap, and I also had to set that to set page transition to none.

Answer (score 1):

Try this **solution**:
There seems to be some problems using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the `<head>` tag, and this solution stops the flickering. But then zoom will not work (I guess)...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Can you please add additional context or citations to help future SO users understand this solution?